# Rspec testing inside a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying to test the code inside a loop, how would I go about this:

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(topics, env, config, limit)
    @client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new(config)
    @topics = topics
    @env = env
    @limit = limit
  end

 def start
   @client.filter(track: @topics.join(",")) do |object|
   # how would I test the code inside here, basically logical stuff
    next if !object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)

    txt = get_txt(object.text)
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I would argue that you do not test the code within the block. Instead you would test that the return value of the method is as expected. Because in theory you do not care if the method is implemented as a loop, with a iterator or if it for example uses a database to solve the problem. So what do you expect your `start` method to return?

Comment: Nothing really, since it is a streaming service I am watching for certain logic and moving to next iterations if not. Pretty much infinite loop, to be honest :) of course, there are some DB ops. How can change this, make it testable. Actually, I thought about breaking down and returning, but then using `next` becomes a pain :(

Answer (score 0):

If think that you can use a `double` of your `Twitter::Streaming::Client` that has a method `filter` and when this method is invoked it returns the desired output:

```
let(:client) { double 'Twitter Client', filter: twitters }
```

You will need to built manually the `twitters` object (sorry by my lack of context but I never used the Twitter client) and then you can make the assertions for the result of the `start` method.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, testing that code is quite tricky. This is because of the dependency on the Twitter client gem.

You can go down couple of paths:

1. Don't test it - the Twitter client gem should provide you with `Twitter::Tweet` objects. You only test your logic, i.e. `get_txt` method
2. Do what @Marcus Gomes said - create a collection double that has the `filter` method implemented.
3. What I would prefer to do is to stub the `@client.filter` call in the spec.

For example, in your spec:

```
some_collection_of_tweets = [
  double(Twitter::Tweet, text: "I'll be back!"),
  double(Twitter::Tweet, text: "I dare ya, I double dare ya!")
]
@my_class = MyClass.new(topics, env, config, limit)
allow(@my_class.client).to receive(:filter).and_return(some_collection_of_tweets)
```

This means that the `some_collection_of_tweets` collection will be returned every time the class calls `@client.filter`, and by having the data built by you, you what expectations to set.

One thing that you will have to change is to set an `attr_reader :client` on the class. The only side effect of this type of testing is that you are tying your code to the interfaces of the Twitter client.

But like everything else... tradeoffs :)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this if you really wanted to test your infinite loop logic?

```
RSpec.describe MyClass do
  subject { MyClass.new(['foo','bar'], 'test', 'config', 1) }

  let(:streaming_client) { Twitter::Streaming::Client.new }

  describe '#start' do
    let(:valid_tweet) { Twitter::Tweet.new(id: 1) }

    before do
      allow(Twitter::Streaming::Client).to receive(:new)
        .with('config').and_return(streaming_client)
    end

    after { subject.start }

    it '#get_txt receives valid tweets only' do
      allow(valid_tweet).to receive(:text)
        .and_return('Valid Tweet')

      allow(streaming_client).to receive(:filter)
        .with(track: 'foo,bar')
        .and_yield(valid_tweet)

      expect(subject).to receive(:get_txt)
        .with('Valid Tweet')
    end

    it '#get_txt does not receive invalid tweets' do
      allow(streaming_client).to receive(:filter)
        .with(track: 'foo,bar')
        .and_yield('Invalid Tweet')

      expect(subject).not_to receive(:get_txt)
    end
  end
end
```